# Do plumeria with inflo need fertilizer to actually bloom?

Tags: houseplants, flowering, tropical

[image]

My plumeria appears to have an inflo! It grew from a cutting that I planted about a year ago. It’s got quite a few large leaves and I planted it in fox farms organic soil. I’m wondering if I need to give it fertilizer. If I don’t, will the inflo have trouble blooming? It gets lots of direct sunlight every day.

If I do need to fertilize it, what’s the best fertilizer to use? I’m scared to use Miracle Gro as I’ve had horrible experiences using it in the past, but maybe I just wasn’t using it correctly.

Any help much appreciated! Don’t want my first inflo to go to waste!!

Comment: What the fudge is an "inflo"? A flowering plant needs a high phosphorus fertilizer regularly during the growing season. Re: MiracleGro, don't believe most of what you read. Fertilizers aren't applied in a vacuum, there is lots more going on (soil, water, other environmental factors) than most people like to think. It wasn't me, it was the fertilizer, I swear!

Comment: I guess "inflo" is short "inflorescence."

Comment: Plumeria do need full sun nearly all day to bloom.

Answer (score 0):

All plants need some food, fertilizer, just like we humans need food. Most nutrients are water soluble, therefore each time you water, some nutrients wash away. You used an organic potting soil, so buy an organic bloom fertilizer, like mentioned in the previous post, which is higher in phosphorus. Use as directed on the label.

Answer (score 0):

A friend was in horticulture his whole life , ran large commercial greenhouses, his own garden shop,etc. When I would tel him my XYZ was not blooming he would usually say ,"give it some fertilizer". Keep in mind that N is not generally given to encourage flower blooms so don't use any lawn fertilizer ( it is normally high nitrogen). I don' recall ever using MiracleGro , consider it too costly. I like Peters or Jacks ( same company) , usually 9 N -45 P -15 K , water soluble starter . I use it for most stuff ( not lawn , and no vegetables), of course they make other mixes.